# tuple unpacking in python using for loops?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

```
l=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
for (a,b) in list:
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if i%2==0:
            print(b)
            break
        else:
            print(a)
            break
```

output-
2
4
6

expected output-
1
4
5

PLEASE correct it!

Comment: what is your logic for deriving [1, 4, 5] ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis logic is that for the first and third tuple,it should print its 
first digit(i.e 1 and 5) and for second tuple its second digit(4).                                            please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to be more specific about what you want to achieve. 
Based on your "expected output", I assume you want the 1st element when the index is even and the 2nd element when the index is odd.

```
l=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(l):
  val = x if idx%2==0 else y
  print(val)
```

Comment: @harshul1 sure thing :D

Comment: can you please tell any alternative for your code,where there is not enumerate function?  please

Comment: @harshul1 sure thing. but you need to keep in mind that `enumerate` is the most "python" way. If I am using C, and I want to zig-zagging a tuple, I would define a binary flipper. Here is the code in python: ```f = 0
for z in l:
    print(z[f])
    f ^= 1```